# I want to delete old data from a table when a new data inserts

Tags: mysql

I have a table called total_table in which the sum of the amount which has spent by a user will be stored, but every time when a new data enters it will create duplicate values to total table.

[image: Here is my total table]

please check the above image where employee 10 added 100 so the total will be 610, now i need to delete the old data automatically when a new data inserts i.e 510  row must be deleted from the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add unqiue key contraint to the column  name so data redundancy can be ignored.

```
 ALTER TABLE table_name
   ADD UNIQUE (column);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update total column in table, instead of inserting new row

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

`INSERT INTO tableName (employee_name, total) VALUES(10, 100) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total = total + 100;`